# Oracle materialized view is empty

Tags: oracle, refresh, materialized-views

I have created a materialized view over the db link.
This view is created on a table in source DB which gets refreshed 2-3 times a day.
Mview is set to refresh every 12 hours.
But Mview is empty many of the times . I could not find the errors.
staless is undefined in all_mview as mview is created over db link
last_refresh_date shows the value correctly as per the schedule
Compilation status shows needs_compile some times. But even after compilation no data.

So i have to manually refresh the mview every time.

Anyone observed such a behaviour?
As per oracle documentation , this occurs if underlying table goes major changes / network error , source table is not accessible etc issues..

But I am not able to reproduce neither facing any of such issues

Comment: It might help if you included the DDL code for the MV. You should also confirm that the source table actually contains data at the time the MV is refreshing. A complete refresh from an empty source will result in an empty MV. An error in the refresh would not cause the MV to lose old data.

Comment: Source table is not empty.this table is refreshed three times a day and it's not empty.it has historical data . Mv is created using create materialzed view mvname refresh force on demand start with sysdate next sysdate+12/24 as select * from tablename@dblink